# Resampling with replacement

Tags: r, sampling, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to get the (bootstrapped) input data for my model.

Source file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dudzxhozr50uhr7/EddyData_2010.csv?dl=0

```
library("dplyr")
library("readr")
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")

sub <- read_csv("EddyData_2010.csv", 
                col_types = list(col_integer(), col_integer(), col_double(),
                                 col_double(), col_double(), col_double(),
                                 col_double(), col_double(), col_double(),
                                 col_double(), col_double(), col_double()),
                col_names = c("Year", "DoY", "Hour", "NEE", "LE", "H", "Rg",
                              "Tair", "Tsoil", "rH", "Ustar", "VPD")) %>%
  filter(DoY == 170) %>%
  mutate(hour = 1:48) %>%
  select(NEE:hour)

# Number of resampling 
n_resempling <- 1000 
result_resampling <- NULL

# Do the resampling
for (i in 1:n_resempling) {
  result_resampling <- sample(48, 48, replace = T) %>%
    slice(sub, .) %>%
    mutate(resempling_number = i) %>%
    bind_rows(. , result_resampling)
}
```

This generates a resampling with replacement such as

[image]

The output shows 1000 bootstraps resampled with replacement along 48 half-hours that a day have.

Here is my problem:

The resampling with replacement is randomly mixing up half-hours along the day without any kind of control. For instance, I am not interested in mixing up half-hours at night and half-hours during the days. The results leads to weird calculations afterwards. Is there any possibility to code this in such a way I define what is allowed and what is not?

Example:

- it is only allowed to resample from 10pm till 5pm
- night hours cannot be resampled with day hours (and vice versa)

Comment: Filter you original data before resampling. Only want to resample between 10am and 5pm? Filter your data so it only includes times in that window, then resample. Only want day hours? Filter your data to day only, then resample...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done naive bootstrap for CRD design but not for time data. Is that time series data? From what I understand, you want 2pm to be sampled only with 2 pm and not 3 pm. Understanding the sampling is important for doing the right analysis because it's really easy to go really wrong in R.

I noticed that you used a loop to bootstrap instead of a package.
I used 'boot' package for naive bootstrap, so I turned to Google to look at time data. Here's what I found, I apologize this is all I've got (I couldn't comment due to lack of rep)
Using boot package I would bet anything is faster than using a loop 
you can check with system.time( ) especially if you have a lot of data.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/boot/html/tsboot.html

Here's how I worked on my naive bootstrap:

```
my.boot.fnx<-function(var, ind,alpha=0.95){
  newdf      <-na.omit(var[ind])
  mymean     <-mean(newdf,na.rm=TRUE)
  mytrimmean <-mean(newdf, trim=0.1, na.rm=TRUE)
  mymedian   <-median(newdf,na.rm=TRUE)
  mysd       <-sd(newdf,na.rm=TRUE)
  nonmiss    <- length(na.omit(newdf))
  semean     <- mysd/sqrt(nonmiss)
  lcl        <- mymean - qt(1-alpha/2,nonmiss-1)*semean
  ucl        <- mymean + qt(1-alpha/2,nonmiss-1)*semean
  mygini     <-
   sum(abs(outer(newdf,newdf,FUN="")))/
   length(newdf)/(length(newdf)-1)*sqrt(pi)/2
   c(mean=mymean,median=mymedian,se=semean, 
   lcl=lcl,ucl=ucl,sd=mysd,gsd=mygini)
#gini coef is a robust measure of SE
}
strap.df <- boot(df$var,statistic=my.boot.fnx, R=1000)
```

I also found this source for time data
http://eranraviv.com/bootstrapping-time-series-r-code/

Also good resource for proper analytical methods for different designs:

http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~cschwarz/CourseNotes/

Anyways, sorry I wasn't too much of help but wanted to share some thoughts.

Comment: Thanks @zazu. The reason why I am doing a "home-made" bootstrap thing is just because out of these outputs, I will get the inputs for the two models that I am trying to assess their uncertainties. Then, I will run each of the models 1000 times. Once I get the outputs, I am interested in the analysis of the 95% confidence interval of the bootstrapped outputs (obtained from each of the models!).

Comment: No worries, just be careful of the method of sample collection before you plunge into bootstrapping. If it is not a CRD you can't just run a Naive bootstrap (I wish I was a stat major to explain the reason why). Here's a link: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/what-are-examples-where-a-naive-bootstrap-fails

Comment: Were you able to do it? Have you tried making time an ordered factor with unique levels?